# Port forwarding from router to machine in LAN not working

Tags: networking, ssh, router, port-forwarding

I have a domain, and am attempting to serve my website from a local machine. Port forwarding on my router does not seem to be working. Here is how I have it set up up, and what I've tried to narrow down the problem:

```
Router: Actiontec GT784WNV
ISP: Verizon
```

- I have a machine in my LAN running apache on port 8086 (let's pretend the IP is 192.168.1.4). I have verified that apache is working, because I can hit that machine's private IP with port 8086 and see my test page.
- I have tested that this port is open, by using a port scanner, and verifying that 8086 is open for my public IP.
- I visited my router's setup page, and set up port forwarding so that port 8086 would forward to the private IP (192.168.1.4 as an example) on port 8086
- To test, I ssh into a machine NOT on my private network, and try to curl the IP of my router with port 8086. The connection is refused.

How can I further debug this issue? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: have you verified your domain is actually pointing to your external ip of the router you are trying to hit? The problem is most likely routing related.

Comment: @Jakub Yes I have verified that. Though even if that part was not working, I should still be able to curl http://<router IP>:8086. This is the part that is failing.

Comment: What's the error message you get when that fails?

Comment: @CIA curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Comment: @Charlotte that's a very explicit and non-descript error.  When you say private IP, do you mean your `127.0.0.1` or the `192.168.1.4`?  Also, can you show a sample of your curl command (obfuscating your public IP of course)?

Comment: @CIA lets say my public IP was 77.777.777.77 and my private is 192.168.1.4 which I'm forwarding to. My curl command would look like curl http://77.777.777.77:8086

Comment: Do you mean: `curl http://77.777.777.77:8086/`? Otherwise, it wouldn't really know what protocol to use.

Comment: @CIA yeah, i added http but it got stripped out of my comment

Comment: @Charlotte can you test with a web browser on a different machine?